# glOrtho appears to have no effect

Tags: opengl

I was drawing a square with coordinates `(-.5, -.5), (-.5, .5), (.5, .5), (.5, -.5)` and I noticed that it appeared squashed in my `800 x 600` window (which seems entirely logical).

I was trying to fix it so that the square appeared square, not rectangular. My approach was to call `glOrtho()` with values of `left = -ar`, `right = ar`, `bottom = -1`, `top = 1` where `ar` was my aspect ratio (`800/600`). What I found was that any call I made to `glOrtho()` had no effect, including the one I was already making (I could remove it and nothing would change).

My understanding of `glOrtho()` is that it maps the corners of the OpenGL context to the values supplied, and stretches everything between those points to fit. Is that incorrect, or am I doing something that's preventing my call to `glOrtho()` from taking effect?

```java
import org.lwjgl.BufferUtils;
import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;

import java.nio.FloatBuffer;

import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL15.*;

public class GLOrthoTestDriver {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(800, 600));
      Display.setTitle("glOrtho Test");
      Display.create();
    } catch (LWJGLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();

      Display.destroy();
      System.exit(1);
    }

    // Initialization code for OpenGL
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glOrtho(-1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1);
    glLoadIdentity();

    // Scene setup

    int vertexBufferHandle;
    int colorBufferHandle;

    FloatBuffer vertexData = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(8);
    vertexData.put(new float[]
        {
          -.5f, -.5f,
          -.5f,  .5f,
           .5f,  .5f,
           .5f, -.5f
        }
    );
    vertexData.flip();

    FloatBuffer colorData = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(12);
    colorData.put(new float[]
        {
          1, 1, 1,
          1, 1, 1,
          1, 1, 1,
          1, 1, 1
        }
    );
    colorData.flip();

    vertexBufferHandle = glGenBuffers();
    colorBufferHandle = glGenBuffers();

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferHandle);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBufferHandle);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
      glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

      glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferHandle);
      glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

      glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBufferHandle);
      glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

      glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
      glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
      glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4);
      glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
      glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

      Display.update();
      Display.sync(60);
    }

    glDeleteBuffers(vertexBufferHandle);
    glDeleteBuffers(colorBufferHandle);

    Display.destroy();
  }
}
```

Comment: Well your code shows glOrtho being called with (-1,1,-1,1...)
Also, if you really are using 800/600 as your aspect ratio, have you ensured that you're using floating point division? (800.0/600.0)  If you are using integer division, you'll just round to ar=1.

Comment: @Anna yes, that was the original call before I tried to de-squash the square. I found that I could change it in any way, or remove it entirely and nothing would change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah - your problem is that you're calling `glLoadIdentity` *after* calling `glOrtho`. `glLoadIdentity` *replaces* the matrix in the current mode (`GL_PROJECTION`) with the identity matrix, thus wiping out any previous call to `glOrtho`.

Try calling `glLoadIdentity` before `glOrtho`.